# How to know who is using a Webapp built with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to publish a free Web App built with Google Apps Script, but I want to know who is using this Web App (user email address at least). The App will be running as the user accessing the App and available to anyone.

I know a way using ScriptDb and saving Session.getUser().getEmail(), but I rather not use this approach for this App.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks, Fausto

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other way other than asking your user for his email address

Comment: thanks +Srik, I have seen GAS webapp asking for authorization while mentioning the script can "View your email address" and I was thinking that was related with collecting user's emails

Answer (score 1):

You can save the user's email anywhere, do it where is more convenient to you. If you don't like `ScriptDb` do it on a `Spreadsheet` for example.

```js
SpreadsheetApp.openById('your-spreadsheet-key').getSheetByName('Sheet1').
  appendRow([new Date(), Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()]);
```

Obviously that this spreadsheet has to be shared to "anyone with the link". Alternatively you could set up a Google Form and send the info using it. It's not a public API but is rather simple to do using `UrlFetch`.

Comment: thanks +Abreu, as I mentioned before, I have seen GAS webapp asking for authorization while mentioning the script can "View your email address" and I was thinking that was related with collecting user's emails > any idea what is that?

Comment: Yes, if your Apps Script code has a `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` call anywhere, when the user is prompted to "install" it Google will inform him that you get his address. What you do with this info is up to you. That's only so the user know his not "anonymous" on your app. Most apps will do that, if you keep any settings at all, so you can differ one user from other.

Comment: Indeed, that was my original idea, however when testing a Web App with just one line in the goGet (var userEmail = Session.getUser().getEmail();) the web app will ask for authorization, however without mentioning "View your email address", nor any services at all

Comment: Have you tested with a different account? Your own is probably different.

Comment: yes i did, from a different domain. You can try as well and let me know what it's asking you for https://script.google.com/a/macros/thexs.ca/s/AKfycbx0t-WfMdRBTiYRkN-OOG8rLNOkSUoZo7Oz0D1rlbp73EUiXOg/exec

Answer (score 1):

You may create another webapp where the current webapp will silently post the active users mail to spreadsheet etc using urlfetch.

Supporting app. Publish it as a webapp to be run under your credentials and with anonymous access. Make sure to get the URL of this webapp. This will be used in main webapp.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var user = e.parameter.user;
  SpreadsheetApp.openById('id of ss where user emailwill be saved').getSheets()[0].getRange('A1').setValue(user);
}
```

In you main webapp
use, following line of code

```
 var user = Session.getActiveUser();
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxx/exec?user='+user); //URL is the supporting webapp url with parameter
```

Comment: thanks +Waqar Ahmad, that looks like a good idea even for other functions // On another view: I have seen GAS webapp asking for authorization while mentioning the script can "View your email address" and I was thinking that was related with collecting user's emails